# C# sql if query

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I try to do

```
var sql = String.Format("if ( {0} > (select sStrength from yCell where Cell_ID = '{1}')) begin UPDATE yCell SET sStrength = {0} WHERE Cell_ID = '{1}' end", inMaxStrength, inCellID);
                   SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sql,connection);
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

there is an error: Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = if 
But in sql studio it runs fine.

Comment: obviously the problem is with what you're passing it.  However, I recommend creating a stored procedure with 2 parameters and doing it that way, outside of the many reasons to do so, it would give you a more meaningful error.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say why it fails, but I can suggest that maybe  you try update in one command:

`UPDATE yCell SET sStrength = {0} WHERE Cell_ID = '{1}' AND {0} > sStrength`